# Smoother ways for setting up a Product function with j=0 and j != i

Tags: polynomials, products

I want to implement a Product function, particularly the Lagrange polynomial

$\ell_{i}(x)=\prod_{j=0 \atop j \neq i}^{n} \frac{x-x_{j}}{x_{i}-x_{j}}$

Are there ways to implement the "not equal" other than with an `If` statement?

Comment: Define the function as the product of two `Product`s

Comment: Have you seen [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)?

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here all functions $l$ in one go as a vector `l`:

```
n = 4;
X = Array[x, n];
id = IdentityMatrix[n];
l = Times @@ Divide[
   Outer[Plus, -X, ConstantArray[x, n]] (1 - id) + id,
   Outer[Plus, -X, X] + id
   ]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can always directly supply an edited index list to `Product[]`:

```
With[{n = 5, i = 3}, 
     Product[(x - \[FormalX][j])/(\[FormalX][i] - \[FormalX][j]),
             {j, DeleteCases[Range[0, n], i]}]]
   ((x - x[0]) (x - x[1]) (x - x[2]) (x - x[4]) (x - x[5]))/
   ((-x[0] + x[3]) (-x[1] + x[3]) (-x[2] + x[3]) (x[3] - x[4]) (x[3] - x[5]))
```

(formal variables edited for clarity)

Comment: Or else `{j,Complement[Range[0,n],{i}]}`, or also `{j,Union[Range[0,i-1],Range[i+1,n]]}`

Answer (score 6):

Using [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html):

```
With[{n = 4, i = 3},
  InterpolatingPolynomial[
    Transpose[{Array[x, n + 1, 0], 
               SparseArray[i + 1 -> 1, n + 1]}], y] // FullSimplify]

(*     (((y-x[0])(y-x[1])(y-x[2])(y-x[4]))/((x[3]-x[0])(x[3]-x[1])(x[3]-x[2])(x[3]-x[4])))    *)
```

Comment: For readability, I'd suggest `Table[{x[j], KroneckerDelta[j, i]}, {j, 0, n, 1}]` to generate your input for `InterpolatingPolynomial` (+1).

Comment: I agree, thanks @MarcoB for for cleaning this up.